# Matlab- How can I plot a function?

Tags: matlab

I created a function that receives certain inputs and produced some outputs for queue theory simulation.

```
  function [Ws, Wq, c_util, p_drop, p_state] =  MMCQ(lambda, mu, c, Nwait)

  rho = lambda./mu;
  Lq = (rho.^2)/(1-rho);  %lenght of queue
  Ls = rho./(1-rho);  %lenght of system
  c_bar = Ls - Lq;
  c_util = c_bar./c ; 
  Wq = Lq/c*mu*c_util;
  Ws = Ls/lambda;

  Po = (1-rho)*(rho.^0);
  Pi = (1-rho)*(rho.^1);
  p_drop = 1-Po-Pi;
  p_state = (1-rho)*rho.^0;


  end
```

I need to create a plot of Wq as a function of c starting at the smallest value of c and stoping at 20. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `plot(c,Wq)`? What have you tried? There is no even `K` in the code you show ...

Comment: I need to define c as increasing from let say 1 to 20

Comment: `for c = 1:20`. Either store your output in an array or `plot(...); hold on;` inside the loop

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: In your code, `Wq` doesn't change as a function of `c`?

Comment: @Wolfie it does change as c changes

Comment: Then you're not showing us all of your code, because the only time `c` is used here is to calcuate `c_util`. Please read how to provide a [mcve] including sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Nope, `Wq = Lq/lambda = ((rho.^2)/(1-rho))/lambda = (((lambda./mu).^2)/(1-(lambda./mu)))/lambda`... so `Wq` is a function of your inputs `lambda` and `mu` only, explicitly **not** `c`?

Comment: @Wolfie you are right. I have redefined Wq as a function c

Comment: Now `Wq` is also a function of `c_util` before that is defined! You really need to spend some thinking about your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through values of `c`, store results to a matrix (assuming `Wq` is scalar), then plot `Wq` against `c`.

```
% Define lambda, mu, Nwait first
c = (1:20); % List of c values to input
Wq = zeros(size(c));
for ii = 1:numel(c)
    % Only interested in Wq, so use tilde for other outputs
    % Store to (ii)th element of Wq
    [~, Wq(ii), ~, ~, ~] = MMCQ(lambda, mu, c(ii), Nwait)
end
plot(c,Wq);
```